# how to fix the issue of brownie installing in vs code during execution of this pipx install eth-brownie code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, solidity, smartcontracts, brownie

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\runpy.py", line 196, in \_run_module_as_main
return \_run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code_
exec(code, run_globals)
File "c:\\users\\hp\\appdata\\roaming\\python\\python310\\scripts\\pipx.exe\__main_.py", line 7, in \<module\>
File "C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\pipx\\main.py", line 779, in cli
return run_pipx_command(parsed_pipx_args)
File "C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\pipx\\main.py", line 202, in run_pipx_command  
return commands.install(
File "C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\pipx\\commands\\install.py", line 60, in install
venv.install_package(
File "C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\pipx\\venv.py", line 238, in install_package  
subprocess_post_check_handle_pip_error(pip_process)
File "C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages\\pipx\\util.py", line 349, in subprocess_post_check_handle_pip_error
print(completed_process.stderr, file=pip_error_fh, end="")
File "C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\encodings\\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)\[0\]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\\u2502' in position 559: character maps to \<undefined\>
```

i try this code  `python -m pip install --user pipx`, `python -m pipx ensurepath`   and i try to run this code and it run properly but during running this `pipx  install eth-brownie` i am getting error and its stick like barriers to me.